# Chef and Rainbow Array(Checking an array to be a palindrome array)

Tags: java, arrays, palindrome

**[Check the complete problem here](https://www.codechef.com/problems/RAINBOWA)**

Chef likes all arrays equally. But he likes some arrays more equally than others. In particular, he loves Rainbow Arrays.

An array is Rainbow if it has the following structure:

First a1 elements equal 1.
Next a2 elements equal 2.
Next a3 elements equal 3.
Next a4 elements equal 4.
Next a5 elements equal 5.
Next a6 elements equal 6.
Next a7 elements equal 7.
Next a6 elements equal 6.
Next a5 elements equal 5.
Next a4 elements equal 4.
Next a3 elements equal 3.
Next a2 elements equal 2.
Next a1 elements equal 1.
ai can be any non-zero positive integer.
There are no other elements in array.

Help Chef in finding out if the given array is a Rainbow Array or not.
This is my code, runs perfectly on NetBeans but says wrong answer on CodeChef.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class RAINBOWA {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testCases, noOfElements,i,j,k;
    boolean t=false;
    testCases = sc.nextInt();
    int a [][] = new int[testCases][1000];
    String opString[];
    opString = new String[testCases];
    for(i=0; i<testCases; i++)
    {
        noOfElements = sc.nextInt();
        for(j=0; j<noOfElements; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(j=0,k=(noOfElements-1); j<(noOfElements/2); j++,k--)
        {
            if(((noOfElements%2)==0) && a[i][j]==a[i][k])
            {
               t=true;
            }
            else if((noOfElements%2)!=0 && a[i][j]==a[i][k])
            {
                if(a[i][((int)noOfElements/2)-1]+1==a[i][(int)noOfElements/2])
                {
                    t=true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                t=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(t==true)
        {
            opString[i]="yes";
            t=false;
        }
        else
            opString[i]="no";
    }
    for(i=0; i<testCases; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(opString[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

java 100% solution for ( Chef and Rainbow Array Problem Code: RAINBOWA)

```
 import java.util.*;
 class Rainbowa
 {
   public static String rainbowa(int[] s)
   {
       int i,j,n=s.length;
       if(s[0]!=1)
         return "no";

       for(i=0,j=n-1;i<j;i++,j--)
          if((s[i]!=s[j]) || (s[i+1]-s[i]>1 )|| ( s[i+1]-s[i]<0 ) || (s[i]<1 )|| (s[i] > 7))
               break;

          if(i<j || s[i]!=7)
             return "no";
       return "yes";
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       int t;
       t=sc.nextInt();
       for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
       {
          int n,val;
          n=sc.nextInt();
          int[] Arr=new int[n];
          for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
          {
              Arr[j]=sc.nextInt();
          }
           String str = rainbowa(Arr);
           System.out.println(str);
       }
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope following solution is the cleanest

```
public static String isRainbowArray(int[] arr) {
        if(arr == null || arr.length == 0) return "no";

        int currentNumber = 1;
        int mid = arr.length/2;
        int left = 0;
        int right;

        while (left <= mid) {
            right = arr.length - 1 - left;
            if(arr[left] == currentNumber && arr[right] == currentNumber) {
                left++;
                continue;
            }

            currentNumber++;
            if(arr[left] != currentNumber || arr[right] != currentNumber) {
                return "no";
            }
        }

        return currentNumber == 7 ? "yes": "no";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class rainbow {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        int n,flag=0,no;

        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number of iterations");

        no=in.nextInt();

        for(int z=0;z<no;z++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the value of n");
            n=in.nextInt();

            int[] a=new int[n];

            System.out.print("Enter the values of array");

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=in.nextInt();

            if((a[n/2]+1)==a[n/2] || (a[n/2]+1)>a[n/2]) {
                for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++) {
                    if(a[i]==a[i+1] || a[i+1]==a[i]+1) {
                        int m=n-1;

                        for(int j=0;j<n/2;j++) {
                            if(a[i]==a[(n-1)-i])
                                flag=1
                            else
                                flag=0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        flag=0;
                }
            }
            else
                flag=0;

            if(flag==1)
                System.out.print("rainbow array\n");
            else
                System.out.print("not a rainbow array\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

codechef-chef-and-rainbow-array-problem
100% solved c++ solution

```
   #include<bits/stdc+++.h>
   using namespace std;
   string rainbowa(vector<int> s)
   {
     if(s[0]!=1)
         return "no";
     int i,j,n=s.size();
     for(i=0,j=n-1;i<j;i++,j--)
         if(((s[i]!=s[j]) || s[i+1]-s[i]>1 || s[i+1]-s[i]<0  || s[i]<1 || s[i] > 7))
            break;;

     if(i<j || s[i]!=7)
       return "no";
    return "yes";
   }

int main()
{
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(NULL);
  int q;
  cin >> q;
  while(q--)
  {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> arr;
    for (int q_itr = 0; q_itr < n; q_itr++)
    {
        int s;
        cin>>s;
        arr.push_back(s);
    }
    string s = rainbowa(arr);
    cout<<s<<endl;
 }
  return 0;}
```

Comment: I think OP wants a Java solution

Comment: java solution is also posted below this page... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50978592/8554538